# Heroku: Update Node to latest version

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, heroku-cli, n

I would like to update my node version to latest version possible on my local machine. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am currently finding trouble to update with methods available to my best of [knowledge](https://askubuntu.com/a/480642/566919). Please note that `heroku-cli` is up to date(as of yet).

```
$ check-node-version
node: 8.3.0
npm: 5.4.2
yarn: 1.2.1
```

Here are other important commands which may help

```
harman@manchanda: 04:14 pm ~ $ node -v
v8.3.0

harman@manchanda: 04:14 pm ~ $ which node
/usr/local/heroku/bin/node

harman@manchanda: 04:15 pm ~ $ nodejs -v
v8.7.0

harman@manchanda: 04:15 pm ~ $ which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs

harman@manchanda: 04:15 pm ~ $ heroku -v
heroku-cli/6.14.34-1fcf80e (linux-x64) node-v8.6.0

harman@manchanda: 04:15 pm ~ $ n
node/6.2.2
node/6.7.0
node/7.0.0
node/7.8.0
node/7.9.0
node/8.4.0
node/8.7.0
```

Let me know if any other information is needed for same?

Comment: you want to update node on your local machine or update node, that is in your heroku dyno?

Comment: on my local machine

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have installed `n` package on your local machine, you can run

```
sudo n latest
```

to update Node to the latest version available (8.7.0 at the moment of writing this answer)

Or, if you want to use the latest Node in your heroku dyno:

1. Open your local project's root
2. Open `package.json`
3. Add `"engines": { "node": "8.7.0" },` like that:

```
{
   "name":"node-example",
   "version":"1.0.0",
   "description":"This example is so cool.",
   "main":"web.js",
   "scripts":{
      "test":"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "keywords":[
      "example",
      "heroku"
   ],
   "author":"jane-doe",
   "license":"MIT",
   "engines":{
      "node":"8.7.0"
   }
}
```

4. `git add package.json && git commit -m "Specified node version"`
5. `git push heroku master`

[Reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node)

Comment: I need to update on my local machine
`sudo n latest` doesn't work... Its still `v8.3.0` for `node -v`
though its, `v8.7.0` for `node -v`